# New to php.mysqli and stuck on a select query

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I am trying to make an Ajax call to the following code, but I get nowt but a 500 error.  Any pointers on what I did wrong would be most welcome.  Thanks

```
if isset(($_POST['lodgeChoice']))
{
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Includes/datalogin.php';
    $lodgeChoice = $_POST['lodgeChoice'];
    $startDate = $_POST['dateChosen'];
    $duration = $_POST['duration'];

    $endDate = strtotime($startDate. ' + ' . $duration . ' days');

    $mysql_query = 'SELECT id FROM bookings WHERE (the_date BETWEEN "' . $startDate . '" AND "' . $endDate . '") AND id_item = ' . $lodgeChoice;

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE (the_date BETWEEN "?" AND "?") AND (id_item = ?)');
        $stmt->bind_param("sss",$startDate, $endDate,$lodgeChoice);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($count);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        return ($count > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE);

}
```

Comment: Turn on error displaying first: `display_errors(1)` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: @Hast: Don't you mean `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat sorry, yes.

Comment: Thanks, but I have
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend using a code editor that supports syntax highlighting, because you'll see your errors very clearly.

I pasted your code into Netbeans, and it instantly flagged up errors on both the `if` statements in your code.

The first one: you don't have brackets around the if condition. (you also have too many brackets around the post variable, but that won't cause any errors)

```
if isset(($_POST['lodgeChoice']))
  ^                              ^
bracket reqd here              and here
```

The second one, you have a semi-colon  at the end, which is wrong, and you don't have any curly brackets around the code you want to be in the `if()`.

```
//removed ; from end of the if() line:
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE (the_date BETWEEN "?" AND "?") AND (id_item = ?)')
{    //added this line
    .....
    .....
}   //added this line as well.
```

Hope that helps.

As I say, a decent code editor will make your life a vast amount easier. And since you can get some very good editors for free, there's really no reason not to be using one.

Comment: Thank you muchly.  All that head scratching for a bracket and a semi-colon.  All working nicely now thanks.

Comment: and as per your recommendation webmatrix went out the window and netbeans is installed (and much better).